# javascript will not load unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website that was started off by someone else. That person built the whole thing in one 1000-line html file, and links to different 'pages' just reference other sections in the main html file. So my task is to break the page apart into seperate html pages. Unfortunately, now the seperate pages do not load the javascript unless the page is refreshed.

Is there a standard way to fix this problem without forcing the user to manually refresh the page?

Comment: What do you mean not loading? We need code

Comment: You're going to have to put the appropriate `<script>` tags in each page that uses the javascript.

Comment: the JS will not actually do anything to the page until you refresh. Which code should I post? the html or JS?

Comment: @Johnathan, I did that. I actually started off by breaking off one section to see how to do it. I just copied al the CSS and JS tags in the head and pasted them in the new file

Comment: @yazan, just give us one of the pages that doesn't load the js unless it's refreshed.

Comment: only post one of the pages that is having a problem, not all 1000 lines

Comment: The markup is probably not very clean. My apologies, I still haven't figured out what exactly is needed for the page and what is extra

Answer (score 0):

If you break that one big page into several smaller pages, make sure you include the JavaScript (and CSS) in the new pages.  The most efficient way to do this is to have the JavaScript in an external JavaScript file, and bring that file into the new pages by putting the script tag inside the new pages' head tags like so:

```
<head>
      <script src="path/to/javascript/app_name.js"></script>
</head>
```

When the user clicks on a hyperlink to see one of the new pages, when the browser receives the response from the server, it will parse the response and execute the JavaScript.

Comment: The tags were already between the head tags, but when that didnt work, I looked around and supposedly you are supposed to put them in the body for the JS to load and that's what I tried. Still a no go

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would wrap whatever "detailsScreen.js" does into a function and call it after you changed the page content.

Comment: What exactlydo you mean by change the page content? And how would that be better/worse than using the notation suggested by Andrew Koper? Especially since the JS is relatiely complicated and there are a number of JS files

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you. You dynamically load the html that was in the page before via JavaScript now? Then you have to probably rerun the JS that renders the charts over this new html after loading

Comment: No, it's just a simple 'a href' to another html page, but that html page does not load its javascript unless you manually refresh it

Comment: That is weird. There should be no difference between loading the page when clicking on the link vs manual refresh. Perhaps some weird timing thing going on? Is the JS wrapped in a jQuery document.ready function?